# How to define a filtration on a Lie object?

Tags: category-theory, lie-algebras

There exists a category of linear maps defined by Loday-Pirashvili. The objects of the category of linear maps are $K$-linear maps $f: V \to W$, where $V$ and $W$ are $K$-vector spaces denoted by $(V,W)$. There exists a Lie object in this category. A Lie object in this category is equivalent to a linear map $f: M \to L$, where $L$ is a Lie algebra, $M$ is a right $L$-module and $f$ is $L$-equivariant.  Now I am eager to know how can we define a descending filtration on this Lie object and associated graded Lie object? For example, we have a descending central series of Lie algebras, and then we can consider a graded Lie algebra associated to the filtration.